# LightFM on AWS sagemaker | Is it possible to train model

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using LightFM for recommender system 
https://github.com/lyst/lightfm

Now I want to move my model to AWS Sagemaker where this is not part of build in algorithm, now I want to train my model using this algorithm and also want to leverage Sagemaker capability for huge data, I am following this link to run my custom model 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms.html

Now, it seems I need to install docker image of this algorithm and too much other things too, is it any simple way to train my model without pre-build algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put the algorithm into a docker container and bring it to SageMaker for training. You may want to check out SageMaker sample notebooks to get some examples of preparing the docker images. For example, https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/r_bring_your_own

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer